# How to hide dynamics for only one voice channel in Guitar Pro 7?

Tags: guitar-pro

How to hide dynamics, the mezzo-forte (mf), in my score sheet for specific voice channels in Guitar Pro 7? I know I can [hide dynamics for all channels](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000411945-GP7-5-Display-or-hide-dynamics), but that's not what I want.

In my score sheet, I sometimes need to use different voice channels to get the rhythm I want. This will add new dynamics (the mf) in the score sheet when I apply the new voicing in a bar later in the piece.

| Voicing channel | image |
| --- | --- |
| Voice 1 mf first bar | [image: Channel 1] |
| Voice 2 mf first bar | [image: Channel 2] |
| Voice 3 mf second bar | [image: Channel 3] |

The only workaround I found was to apply overlapping notes on all the voice channels on the same note in the first bar.

[image: Workaround]

Answer (score 1):

After searching through [the manual](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002399509-GP7-5-Guitar-Pro-7-5-User-s-guide-), I couldn't find anything about hiding dynamics for a specific channel.